# Access class variable value of a Python subclass that was defined in abstract superclass in implemented function within abstract superclass

Tags: python, abstract-class, subclass, superclass, class-variables

I try to achieve the following:

- Require `class_variable` to be "implemented" in `ConcreteSubClass` of `AbstractSuperClass`, i.e. make `AbstractSuperClass.class_variable` abstract
- Define implemented (concrete) `method` in `AbstractSuperClass` which accesses the "implemented" value of `ConcreteSubClass.class_variable`

I would like to do this so that I won't have to implement `method` within all `ConcreteSubClass`es of `AbstractSuperClass`.

If I run the below code:

```
from abc import ABC


class AbstractSuperClass(ABC):
  class_variable: int
  
  def method(self):
    return self.instance_variable * AbstractSuperClass.class_variable
    

class ConcreteSubClass(AbstractSuperClass):
  class_variable: int = 2
  
  def __init__(self, instance_variable):
    self.instance_variable = instance_variable
    
concrete_subclass = ConcreteSubClass(instance_variable=2)
print(concrete_subclass.method())
```

The code fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 19, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 8, in function
AttributeError: type object 'AbstractSuperClass' has no attribute 'class_variable'
```

Which is reasonable, because the value of `class_variable` is not assigned in `AbstractSuperClass`, but suspicious because `AbstractSuperClass` *has* attribute `class_variable`.

I would like to achieve the below:

```
def method(self):
    return self.instance_variable * <refer to cls of the concrete subclass this method will be called>.class_variable
```

How can I do this?

Comment: use the builtin https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @a_r's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76494832/4169924), I came up with the solution where most of the code is in `AbstractSuperClass` and `ConcreteSubClass`es only need to define and implement minimal stuff:

```
from abc import ABC

class AbstractSuperClass(ABC):
  _class_variable: int
  
  @classmethod
  def class_variable(cls) -> int:
    return cls._class_variable
  
  def method(self):
    return self.instance_variable * self.class_variable()
    
class ConcreteSubClass(AbstractSuperClass):
  _class_variable: int = 2
  
  def __init__(self, instance_variable):
    self.instance_variable = instance_variable
    
concrete_subclass = ConcreteSubClass(instance_variable=2)
print(concrete_subclass.method())
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. I hope it works :

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
class AbstractSuperClass(ABC):
@property
@classmethod
@abstractmethod
def class_variable(cls):
    pass

def method(self):
    return self.instance_variable * self.class_variable

class ConcreteSubClass(AbstractSuperClass):
class_variable = 2

def __init__(self, instance_variable):
    self.instance_variable = instance_variable

@classmethod
def class_variable(cls):
    return cls.class_variable

concrete_subclass = ConcreteSubClass(instance_variable=2)
    print(concrete_subclass.method())
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do here, and it is helpful, but I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'method'` because `self.class_variable` in `method` is a method, but the value of `class_variable`.